# Problem with vspace around table environment

Tags: tables, spacing, tabularx

I recently decided I wanted a caption for the top table, so I placed it in a `table` environment. When I did this, the `\vspace*{-2.5cm}` before the second table seemed to be ignored for some reason. Does anyone know why? How I can overcome this problem?

```
\begin{center}
\begin{table}
\caption{My Table}
\begin{tabular}
...
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{center}

\newpage
\vspace*{-2.5cm}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}
...
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

If I remove the `table` environment then the `\vspace*{-2.5cm}` works again.

Comment: Never put a `center` environment around a `table` environment; instead, put `\centering` after `\begin{table}`

Comment: @egreg thanks, but can you explain why? Also, this seems to have centered the table vertically now.

Comment: The `table` environment defines a "floating object". Every LaTeX guide describes them.

Comment: @egreg I see. So the `tabular` environment is not a floating object and this is why the `vspace` no longer works?

Comment: @Alex See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures

Comment: @Alex It's quite a bad idea to say `\vspace*{-2.5cm}` after `\newpage` anyway. Why should one want it?

Comment: @egreg yeah I realise it's probably not the best way of doing what I wanted to do, but it seemed to be the easiest. The table doesn't fit within the margins of the page, so I was raising it into the top margin. Any better ways of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly, you want to have the first part of some tabular material set on one page and the remaining tabular material at the very top of the next page. To force LaTeX to typeset the pending `table` float on the current page rather than defer it to some later point in the document that LaTeX's float-placement algorithm may deem to be appropriate, you should use `\clearpage` rather than `\newpage`, as `\clearpage` instructs LaTeX to "flush out" all pending floats (as well as start a new page). I take it that you've already ascertained that the first tabular enviroment -- the one that's currently encased in a `table` environment -- does fit on the intended page. You want to specify `[htb!]` as the placement directive for the table to give LaTeX maximum flexibility.

Or are you maybe looking to create a table that can span more than one page? If so, do check out the [longtable](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/longtable), [supertabular](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/supertabular), and [xtab](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xtab/) environments. Unlike the standard LaTeX `table` environment, which can not cross page boundaries, these environments can all span multiple pages.

**Addendum**. As @egreg already suggested in a comment, don't use `\begin{center}` ... `\end{center}`; instead, use `\centering` after the `\caption` command and before the `\begin{tabular}{...}` command. The `center` environment inserts extra vertical whitespace, which is probably not what you want to achieve; the `\centering` macro centers everything in its scope but does not insert extra vertical whitespace.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried using `\clearpage`, but it seems to be inserting a blank page and the `\vspace` is still being ignored.

Comment: @Alex: Having a MWE would be helpful as there are many possibilities as to what may be going on. Regarding the matter of where the tabular material starts on the second page, have you tried `\vspace*{-2.5cm}` instead of `\vspace{-2.5cm}`? At least when I use the `\vspace*` instruction between `\clearpage` and `\begin{tabular}...`, LaTeX dutifully moves the tabular stuff up by the specified amount.-

Comment: Would I not have to post a table large than a page to provide a MWE? I think if I can simply alter the top margin for the second table page then it should work. Yes I have, that's what's in my code at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it's fixed now. Adding `\clearpage` and then putting `\vspace*{-2.5cm}` after `\begin{center}` worked perfectly. If you look at my original code the `\vspace*{-2.5cm}` was before the `\begin{center}` which was not working.

Comment: I'm glad you're all set!